# Can we force Mathematica to separate fractions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

For instance an expression like this

$$\frac{ab+bc+ac}{abc}=\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$$

```
expr = (a b + b c + a c )/(a b c)
```

Simplify, makes Mathematica always go to the first expression, but I would prefer to have the second one.

Comment: `(a b + b c + a c )/(a b c) // Simplify[#, ComplexityFunction-> Count[Times[__]] ]&` may also works.

Comment: `Expand[expr]`.

Comment: `(a b + b c + a c)/(a b c) /. Plus -> List /. List -> Plus` :)

Answer (score 4):

```
expr = (a b + b c + a c )/(a b c)

Distribute[expr]
```

or

```
Expand[expr]
```

or

```
Collect[expr, Variables@expr]
```

---

> 1/a + 1/b + 1/c

Comment: interestingly, `Apart[expr]` gives only `(a + b)/(a b) + 1/c`.

Comment: @murray - `Apart /@ (expr // Apart)`

Comment: @BobHanlon: Yes, I was aware of repeated `Apart`, just surprised that a simple application of it did not fully separate the fractions.

Comment: @murray An internal trace show `Apart` expanding the fraction completely, then combining `1/a + 1/b`. I think it's performing `Apart[expr, c]`, where the variable `c` is chosen somehow (but that does not show up in the trace).

Answer (score 1):

Using `Apart` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
f = (a b + b c + a c)/(a b c);
vars = Variables[f];

Apart[f, vars] /. x_ + y_ :> Most@SortBy[{y, x}, Count[Times[_]]] /. z_ :> Total[z][[1]]

(*1/a + 1/b + 1/c*)
```

Or using `Level`:

```
Total@Most@Level[f, {1}]

(*1/a + 1/b + 1/c*)
```